# Why is my 2012 Chevy Equinox heater only blowing cold air?

Tags: chevrolet, heater, equinox

In my 2012 Chevy Equinox, when turning the heater on it only blows cold air like the AC is on.

1. Temperature gauge is normal as it always has been
2. No leaking fluids, including water
3. The seat warmers work

Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you checked the coolant level? Your temperature gauge may be normal, but low coolant can cause lack of heat inside the vehicle. Also, please refrain from using ALL CAPS. It is actually more difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise the front end of your car and open the coolant reservoir cap (not the overflow), make sure engine is cold or the coolant will blow out and scold you, but what you're looking for is basically air in the system.

Even though the coolant level may seem full there may be air trapped in the system.

To get the air out you can turn the engine on, turn heater to max heat and full speed, and squeeze on the hoses that go into the radiator and see if any air bubbles come out.

If this doesn't work you may have a broken heater core.

Comment: Good first answer. What do you mean by broken heater core? Wouldn't that be evident by leaking coolant?

Comment: Good point about there not being any leaks. That's good than as this may indicate air in the system, however not sure why there would be air in there in the first place unless work was done that caused loss coolant in the first place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just purchased a 2012 Equinox and had the same issue. I took it in and the service manager checked the coolant and it was fine. He then turned the temperature control to the cold ( blue color) and then it blew out hot air. The heat ( red color) blows out cold air. Everything seems to work fine, it's just that they are backwards. I don't know if this helps.